# how to connect ethernet using lwip and microblaze

Tags: lwip

I am trying to use lwip and micro blaze to talk to a web api. 
I am unable to find a way to connect micro-blaze to internet. I have nexys 4 board, it has Ethernet port. I have looked at lwip tutorial on xilinx website but it assumes i have internet connection establish. please can anyone point me in the right direction on how to connect to internet using lwip and micro-blaze?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you look at the example project? In SDK, File -> New -> Application Project. You will have the option to select "lwIP echo server" in the templates tab.

Comment: i did do that but that creates a web server on microblaze. it will not connect to internet but will let pc to talk to web server that was creates on microblaze. in otherwords, i want microblaze to be a client and not web server. please let me know if i am missing some thing here. thank you for your time.

Comment: If you connect the example to a router set up properly, you will have internet access on the microblaze. In the default configuration, it expects the router to be at 192.168.1.1. You can setup dhcp, but it should be unecessary.

Comment: so if i follow this document, http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp1026.pdf - will i be able to plug in ethernet cable into router in my house and get internet access to microblaze? are there any other examples out there? because if i understand it right, you can' give static ip to a router. can you? i searched for several hours and most of the hits were refering to this document. i am new to this stuff so my questions might seems silly.

Comment: please can you help me understand how can i connect microblaze to ethernet port? document has examples about web server and echo server.

Comment: Your problem seems more like a networking issue than a microblaze/lwIP one. If you can connect to the echo server through a router, it means your microblaze has internet access if it configured it's gateway properly. I don't think Xilinx's lwIP has DNS though, so you will have to access your server through ip address and not domain name.

Comment: thank you for your response. reality is that i am a student and all this is new to me. i downloaded reference design from xilinx web site. however, i am not able to find for most of the methods that are called from in main(). do we have to write them or is it hidden some where?

Comment: i downloaded reference design from 1026 app note, and i also tried to create  In SDK, File -> New -> Application Project->Iwip echo server.  there many missing references in main.c, like where is lwip_init() defined. none of the files in include have this function. so does it mean that i have write code for lwip_init()? when i do  In SDK, File -> New -> Application Project->lwip_server, does it create a complete application in itself or do i have to add to it? transfer_data() has only return 0, which is clearly not right. do you have any example for lwip? thank you for your help on this.

Comment: app note says, i must connect my board to my laptop, but you are saying something else. how should i connect my board, if i get it working at all.

Comment: If you connect the microblaze to your laptop, it will only be able to access to your laptop IP address (unless your laptop is configured as a gateway). But it is simpler since it has less places to "break". The Xilinx's lwIP example has been known to break from version to version, Vivado 2014.3 seems fine. Not 100% sure, but transfer_data may be obsolete, data transfer is done through interrupts.